# How to compare multiple rows in a group in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rows

I would like to compare all the rows in a group to find the correct order of the events. My sample data frame has a similar structure:

```
Group  Prev_Event    Current_Event        Time
001    Blank         Initial        2019-02-13 18:00:00   
001    Ready         Loading        2019-02-13 18:00:00
001    Initial       Ready          2019-02-13 18:00:00
001    Loading       Executing      2019-02-13 18:30:00
001    Executing     Evaluating     2019-02-13 18:30:00
001    Evaluating    Terminating    2019-02-13 18:30:00
002    Blank         Ready          2019-02-14 07:00:00
```

By comparing and matching the Prev_Event with the Current_Event, corresponding timestamp of that data point is modified by adding 1 s. However, if the timestamp value is different from the previous data point, then I would want to keep the original timestamp.

Note: My data has loops where there are multiple data points where the Prev_Event matches with Current_Event, therefore, graphs could not be used.

My expected output is:

```
Group   Prev_State   Current_State   New_Timestamp
001    None          Initial        2019-02-13 18:00:00   
001    Ready         Loading        2019-02-13 18:00:02
001    Initial       Ready          2019-02-13 18:00:01
001    Loading       Executing      2019-02-13 18:30:00
001    Executing     Evaluating     2019-02-13 18:30:01
001    Evaluating    Terminating    2019-02-13 18:30:02
002    Blank         Ready          2019-02-14 07:00:00
```

I think I need to use a basic function using shift to iterate over multiple rows in the group and compare with Prev and Current event variables and order them but I am not sure how to apply.
Any help would be appreciated.

Also, in some special cases, there are certain data points that do not follow the pattern where the prev event does not match with the current event of other data points; In those cases, randomly order has to be assigned.

**ADDITIONAL EXAMPLE:**

```
Group   Prev_State   Current_State   Timestamp             New_Time
    001    None        Initial      2019-02-13 18:00:00  2019-02-13 18:00:00
    001    Ready       Loading      2019-02-13 18:00:00  2019-02-13 18:00:02 
    001    Initial     Ready        2019-02-13 18:00:00  2019-02-13 18:00:01
    001    Initial     Waiting      2019-02-13 18:30:00  2019-02-13 18:30:00
    001    Waiting     Ready        2019-02-13 18:30:00  2019-02-13 18:30:01
    001    Evaluating  Terminating  2019-02-13 18:30:00  2019-02-13 18:30:02
    002    Blank       Ready        2019-02-14 07:00:00  2019-02-14 07:00:00
```

Here in Row 3 and Row 4 (Prev_State), both have the same 'Initial' state that could be matched with the first row('Current_State), therefore, any of the above could be chosen for the order.
In the last row of Group 1, Prev_State could not be matched with any of the current_State, hence the an independent order has to be assigned to it.

This is a sample of my data set.

Comment: Why is there a 2s increase for second row, even though there is no matching `Prev_Event` and `Current_Event` ?

Comment: It is because the data points are not sorted in the order. It was a deliberate attempt to show that my data is not sorted where the Prev event matches with the Current event. In some cases, for some data points, Prev does not match with the current and then for those special cases, just random order has to be assigned

Comment: I think it would be good to give an example of a problematic group that requires random ordering. I still think a Directed Network Graph is the easiest way to find the order, but it will require some work to deal with groups that contain cycles and/or disjoint segments.

Comment: ALollz: I tried identifying the cycles and it turns out it was almost more than 50 percent of the data set. However, I will provide the example in the question (edits) to be specific. Thanks